# Can I generate URLs to point to Google Maps on all platforms and perform some actions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-urls

Regardless of the platform I would like to launch Google Maps and optionally perform some actions like showing location, route etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google provides Google Maps URLs which allows you to do just that.  You can build a universal, cross-platform URL to launch Google Maps and perform searches, get directions and navigation, and display map views and panoramic images. The URL syntax is the same regardless of the platform in use.

You don't need a Google API key to use Google Maps URLs.

[Google Map URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide)

Answer (score 1):

Recently, in May 2017, Google launched the new Google Maps URLs API. You can read about this API in the official documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

This API is intended to provide universal, cross-platform Google Maps URLs. So you can use it with websites, mobile apps, etc.

Search, directions, display map and display street view panorama modes are available in this API.

I hope this helps!